# Could not load file or assembly '$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I've a empty project sharepoint 2013 and a webservice .asmx

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Debug="true" Class="TeamForce.FolderTranslation.AppCode.FolderTranslationWS, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"  %>
```

When i go to the asmx in the browser, i've an exception, here is the complete stack trace:

```
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly '$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$' could not be loaded.



=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$
(Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$ | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.    
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\bin
Calling assembly : System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file:       C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET   Files/root/cc15250f/7a72a687/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cc15250f/7a72a687/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$/  $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/_app_bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/_app_bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cc15250f/7a72a687/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cc15250f/7a72a687/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/_app_bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.EXE.
 LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/80/_app_bin/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$/$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$.EXE.
```

I've added the refence sharepoint and copy to local set in true.

Comment: Did you add `.asmx` to the list of files Visual Studio should magically replace such `$`-variables in? (Found [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/182473/how-to-create-an-asmx-web-service-on-sharepoint-2010-using-v.aspx) on Google. See [Picture](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-B727FHQqsz8/T9zFqJS0BXI/AAAAAAAABLw/GjUlASZ_voQ/s1600/Step6.png)).